# how to generate an empty highchart in absence of data

Tags: highcharts

I have an application where no data might come, I want to generate an empty high chart in that case.
How can I do it ?
I would like to display text "no data" inside teh graph at centre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to use the `no-data-to-display` module, which can be added simply by including this in your code ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NVX3S/673/)):

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>
```

This code shows some usage examples of the module functionality ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/hxGmq/)):

```
if(!chart.hasData()) {  // Only if there is no data
    chart.hideNoData(); // Hide old message
    chart.showNoData("Your custom error message");
}
```

You could alternatively create your own code to do some checks against the data of the chart, but you might end up having a lot of cases depending on the chart type. The text itself can be created using `chart.renderer.text`.